# WindowsForm Picturebox in WPF

Tags: wpf, resize, picturebox, autoresize

I found this cool application which lets you have a webcam connection with your home network but it uses a PictureBox to show the webcam stream.

I got a PictureBox to work in WPF, but it doesn't seem to resize.

**Example:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/mpEsN.png

What am I doing wrong?

This is my current XAML Code:

```
<Grid>
    <wfi:WindowsFormsHost>
        <winForms:PictureBox  x:Name="pictureBoxLoading">
        </winForms:PictureBox>
    </wfi:WindowsFormsHost>
</Grid>
```

Comment: It seems like I accidentally deleted the answer someone posted, but it said:
add Dock="Fill" but it didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

I assume in your code you're not using native WPF Image control. Any native WPF control can automatically resize when included in a grid or in a Viewbox.

Because you're using Windows Forms control, you have to handle the resize yourself, because *WindowsFormsHost only host Windows Forms control, NOT interacting with it as a normal WPF control*.